# Animation Nodes. Rotate instanced objects in their individual rotation axis

Tags: animation-nodes

I've been trying to make instanced objects in AN rotate in their individual rotation axis towards the direction of an Empty object. I can get them to rotate towards the correct general direction, but I haven't been able to make them "calculate" this rotation in an "individual" manner, if that makes sense. Here's an image that shows what I have so far and what I'm trying to achieve (the content within the pink bounds):

[image: img_explanation]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a one direction for each object:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get this "unique" value for each instance of the object but I couldn't sucessfully replicate your node tree... Did you test it against an object like the one on my screens? Many thanks though! Also, I've found a very simple solution by adding a "Track to" constraint to the object XD So I'm using AN now, only to replicate the objects...

Comment: Yes used Suzanne to test it. Depending on the configuration, may need to change the axis for "direction to rotation". In the screen capture above, did not take care of it. But should be Y and Z.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a rather simple way, using a blender's "constraint" on my objects. All I've done was added the "Track to" contraint to the object, tracking it to the empty. I've made sure AN copied the contrained by checking all boxes on the instancer node... Here's the result:

[image: solution]